# Vue 3 - Dynamic props are not passed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Component - Groups.vue

```
   <MainTable
      @next="getNextGroup"
      @prev="getPrevGroup"
      @start="getGroups"
      :columns="tableColumns"
      :data="groupsData"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import MainTable from "../../components/MainTable/index.vue";
import { useGroupsStore } from "../../store/groups";
import { onMounted, reactive, ref } from "vue";
const groupStore = useGroupsStore();
let groupsData = reactive([{}]);
let tableColumns = ref([
  {
    label: "Название",
    prop: "title",
  },
  {
    label: "Время",
    prop: "time",
  },
  {
    label: "Количество мест",
    prop: "count",
  },
]);
const getGroups = async () => {
  const res = await groupStore.getGroups();
  console.log("groupsData", groupsData);
};

const getNextGroup = async () => {
  const res = await groupStore.getGroupsNext();
  console.log("groupsData", groupsData);
};
const getPrevGroup = async () => {
  const res = await groupStore.getGroupsPrev();
  console.log("groupsData", groupsData);
};
</script>
```

And parent component- MainTable.vue

```
<script setup>
import { toRefs, onMounted, watch } from "vue";

const emit = defineEmits(["next", "prev", "start"]);
const props = defineProps({
  columns: Array,
  data: Array,
});

let { data: tableData } = toRefs(props);

onMounted(() => {
  emit("start");
});

const next = () => {
  emit("next");

};
const prev = () => {
  emit("prev");

};
</script>
```

I get the data and write it to groupsData, but the data is not updated in MainTable.

I use torres and still an empty array, or just a Proxy comes.

tried using reactive and ref
Or you need to use computed

Why  props may not change reactively?

Comment: I can't see anywhere where you're modifying groupsData? You seem to be fetching data from the store but not doing anything with the `res` value that is returned.

Comment: `const getGroups = async () => {
  groupsData = await groupStore.getGroups();
  console.log("groupsData", groupsData);
};
`
The wrong code was shown by accident, here I assign it and it will not change in props either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you've initialised `groupData` as a reactive object but then you're replacing it with a non reactive object.

There are a couple ways to achieve what you want.

1. Use a reactive object and modify one of its properties rather than replacing the whole object:

```
const data = reactive({ groups: [] });
data.groups = await groups store.getGroups();
```

2. Use `ref` instead of `reactive`

```
const groupsData = ref([]);
groupsData.value = await groupStore.getGroups();
```

Please note that a `ref` is a `Proxy` object. You can refer to `groupData` directly in the template but to get or set its value in the script you have to use `groupData.value` as above.